# Circular motion - vectors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity, vectors

We are asked to show that, if 
$$\frac{{\rm d} \mathbf{r}}{{\rm d}t} = \mathbf{c}\times\mathbf{r},$$
where $\mathbf c$ is a constant vector, then the body moves in uniform circular motion.

I have done this by considering the time derivative of the dot product and showing that this is zero:
$$
\frac{{\rm d}\mathbf r}{{\rm d}t}\cdot\frac{{\rm d}\mathbf r}{{\rm d}t}=0,
$$
and hence that the speed of the body is constant.

We are then asked to show that if $\hat θ$ and $\hat n$ are tangential and unit normal vectors at a point along the path, and $s$ is the scalar length along the path, that 
$$
\frac{{\rm d}\theta}{{\rm d}s}=\frac{1}{r}\hat{n},
$$
where $r$ is the radius of curvature at the point.

Comment: not my downvote, but I think this is a mathSE question, and you could look both there and also read through to the bottom of this: http://edshare.soton.ac.uk/2032/4/diffvectors.pdf

Comment: It's worth noting that $\frac{d\vec r}{dt} \cdot \frac{d\vec r}{dt}$ is emphatically not zero - that would imply that the particle was not moving at all.  I suspect you mean to say that $\vec r \cdot \frac{d\vec r}{dt} = 0$

Comment: Related question asked 7h earlier: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/385363/2451

Comment: Not true in general: the motion will be helical if the initial velocity has any component in the $\hat c$ direction.

Comment: @J.Murray Note that I said the time derivative of the said dot product is zero, not the dot product itself. Is this method correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decompose the normal and tangential unit vectors $\hat {\mathbf n}$ and $\hat {\boldsymbol {\theta}}$ in Cartesian coordinates. From the diagram below we have:
$$\hat {\boldsymbol {\theta}} = -\sin\theta \hat{\mathbf i} + \cos\theta \hat{\mathbf j} $$
$$\hat {\mathbf {n}} = \cos\theta \hat{\mathbf i} + \sin\theta \hat{\mathbf j} $$
Now differentiate both sides of the first equation with respect to $\theta$ to get:
$$\frac {d}{d\theta}\hat {\boldsymbol {\theta}}= -\cos\theta \hat{\mathbf i} - \sin\theta \hat{\mathbf j}  $$
Which by the second equation means:
$$\frac {d}{d\theta}\hat {\boldsymbol {\theta}}= -\hat {\mathbf {n}}   $$
Now since $ds = rd\theta$ (arc length = radius $\times$ angle), we finally get:
$$\frac {d}{ds}\hat {\boldsymbol {\theta}}= -\frac {1}{r}\hat {\mathbf {n}}   $$
The differing minus sign with your equation is probably because of different conventions in choosing the direction of $\hat {\boldsymbol {\theta}}$. I chose the direction of increasing $\theta$ as my convention, as you can see from the diagram below. One can also choose the opposite direction. 
   
                                   
[image]